# Java IO not displaying file data

Tags: java-io, outputstream, datainputstream

Okay, I guess I'm stuck here. Can't get the values from the file to show in JOptionPane's message dialog box where it's enclosed within a while loop.
Right now I don't know which method of Input/Output stream to use to display all the data on this file which I believed to be serialized as UTF8??

Please tell me what to do and what things I missed since I'm new to java.io classes.

Also, the file StudentData.feu was just given to me. It's not that I don't want to research on my own because I already did, I'm just stuck. I read the Javadoc but I'm clueless right now.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyProj {


public void showMenu() {
    String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    (null, "Please enter a number: " + "\n[1] All Students" + "\n[2] BSCS Students" + "\n[3] BSIT Students"
    + "\n[4] BSA Students" + "\n[5] First Year Students" + "\n[6] Second Year Students" + "\n[7] Third Year Students" 
    + "\n[8] Passed Students" + "\n[9] Failed Students" + "\n[0] Exit");

    int choiceConvertedString = Integer.parseInt(choice);

    switch(choiceConvertedString){
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program closed!");
            System.exit(1);
            break;
    }
}

DataInputStream myInputStream;
OutputStream myOutputStream;
int endOfFile = -1;
double grades;
int studentNo;
int counter;
String studentName;
String studentCourse;

public void readFile()
{

    try
    {
        myInputStream = new DataInputStream
            (new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Jordan's Pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyProj\\StudentData.feu"));
        try{

            while((counter=myInputStream.read()) != endOfFile)
            {

            studentName = myInputStream.readUTF();
            studentCourse = myInputStream.readUTF();
            grades = myInputStream.readDouble();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
            (null, "StdNo: " + studentNo + "\n"
                    + "Student Name: " + studentName + "\n"
                    + "Student Course: " + studentCourse + "\n"
                    + "Grades: " + grades);
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
        }

    }/* end of try */

        catch(EOFException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Processing Complete");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured");
        }

}
```

}

Comment: I was able to make it display but this is what I get run:
http://picpaste.com/screenshot-CoOu1hh9.jpg

Comment: Your picture is illegible. Just post the text. How are these files produced? With a `DataOutputStream`? in sequences of an indicator byte, followed by two `writeUTFs()`, followed by a `writeDouble()`? Are they really binary? Because if not, your reading code cannot possibly work.

Comment: @EJP, Files were produced using write*() functions like you mentioned. I know because I was able to display I guess "one row" of it using this code. However, I still need help with displaying all the data from the file. I'm having problems with my While Loop. Here's the updated code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287122/java-io-while-loop-end-of-file

Comment: If the file was really produced exactly as I described you wouldn't have a problem. *Ergo* it wasn't. You need to tell us *exactly* how the file was produced. Not approximately. Don't post links to pictures of text, or code. Post the text, and the code, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while((counter=myInputStream.read()) != endOfFile)
```

The problem is probably here. You're reading a byte and then throwing it away. It isn't likely that the file contains extra bytes like this that are intended to be thrown away. The correct loop would go like this:

```
try
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // .... readUTF() etc
    }
}
catch (EOFException exc)
{
    // You've read to end of file.
}
// catch IOException etc.
```